# Showing picture in Android from HTML with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, html

I'm trying to show a picture in my app using JavaScript, I got the HTML with JavaScript that works perfect, if I open the HTML in IE or Mozilla I see it corretly (I get the picture from a server).

And here is the code in Android:

```
    myBrowser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.mybrowser);

    myBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myBrowser.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    myBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    myBrowser.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    myBrowser.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

    myBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/imagen.html");
```

And when I start the app, it doesn't load the picture...

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

We don't have enough information to make educated guesses as to why.

Where are the images located that are referenced in your HTML?

Do you have the requisite permission added to your manifest for internet access?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Yes, I have this permission. I have also added my JavaScript Code. I Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you have to enable javascript in your WebView?

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Also, you can check if the WebView is genrating an error:

```
 webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

   public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
     Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh noes! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
 });
```

Comment: ok, check if there is an error using the 'webview.setWebViewClient' I provided

Answer (score 0):

Load your HTML code in the WebView. This will work.

```
    String imagePath= "Your Html code"; 
    WebView webView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", imagePath, "text/html","utf-8", "");
```